# Time ago in angular moment js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs, angular-moment

I am using [Moment](https://momentjs.com) js and [Angular Moment](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment) js to calculate time ago for my website. Everything is working perfectly except one thing. I don't know whether is it possible or not. I checked their  [humanize()](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/humanize/) documentation but didn't find anything usefull.

```
<span am-time-ago="messagedata.created | amFromUnix"></span>
```

Result: `a day ago` but i want `1 day ago`. Is it possible? If yes how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those messages depend on the locale used by moment.js but you can update the locale to provide a different version of the messages

```
moment.updateLocale('en', {
    relativeTime : {
        future: "in %s",
        past:   "%s ago",
        s:  "seconds",
        m:  "a minute",
        mm: "%d minutes",
        h:  "an hour",
        hh: "%d hours",
        d:  "a day",
        dd: "%d days",
        M:  "a month",
        MM: "%d months",
        y:  "a year",
        yy: "%d years"
    }
});
```

with the angular directive, you should be able to configure the moment instance when the application starts

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ['angularMoment']);
myapp.run(function(amMoment) {
    amMoment.changeLocale(...);
});
```

you can check the [moment.js documentation about customisation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/) for more details

Comment: Great..works perfectly... just one more thing if i have 2-3 languages then i need to do it manually for each language?

Answer (score 4):

Check [fromnow](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/) section from moment it is what you are looking for, since you want to display the date with respect to today.